# How to add header to row header column in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, rhandsontable

In running the below simple code, I would like to add a column header to the far-left row header column of the table as show in the below image. How would this be done? If this makes a difference, the code is run inside the package `Shiny` but for the sake of brevity in the code below I took the core code out of Shiny.

[image]

I can change row 2, column 1, of the DF dataframe from a value of "2" to "22" with this command: `DF[2,1] <- 22`; but running `DF[0,0] <- c("Header")` gives "*Error in x[[jj]] :
attempt to select less than one element in get1index* ".

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(
  integer = 1:5,
  numeric = rnorm(5),
  factor_allow = factor(letters[1:5], 
                        levels = letters[5:1],
                        ordered = TRUE
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rownames(DF) <- c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five")

rhandsontable(DF,rowHeaderWidth = 96) %>%
  hot_col("factor_allow", allowInvalid = TRUE)
```

Comment: What if you try `DF$Header <- c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five")` instead of `rownames(DF) <- c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five")`?

Comment: That creates a new column on the far right, header label "Header" and then the character strings you list. Instead, I'm trying to fill dataframe cell DF[0,0] with a character string.

Comment: looking at the info I can find for the `rhandsontable` package this isn't a supported function (it's also not something people would typically want, that cell is left blank in basically all standard table layouts I can think of).  One workaround that might be worth exploring would be to add a column called "Header" with the row names in, move it to the left of your data frame, colour it to match the headers and hide the 'real' row names.

Comment: Just to be clear on why your `[0,0]` didn't work - the data frame in R is 1-indexed (i.e. the lowest number for each dimension is 1) and contains ONLY the data.  The names of the columns and rows are attributes of the data frame, not information stored within its structure. 0,0 therefore does not exist, and the text cannot be assigned to that position.  Instead of changing the data frame itself, we need to think of how to change they way it is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not possible to add header to `DF[0,0]`. One workaround is to replace `rowHeaders` with a column instead using dplyr:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(dplyr)

# Renders the same colour as in the rowHeader
color_renderer <- "
  function(instance, td) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.background = '#F0F0F0';
  }
"

DF = data.frame(
  integer = 1:5,
  numeric = rnorm(5),
  factor_allow = factor(letters[1:5],
                        levels = letters[5:1],
                        ordered = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Create your Header column    
DF = DF %>%
  mutate(Header = c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"),
         .before = 1)

# remove rowHeaders from your table, add colour to first column
rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaderWidth = 96, rowHeaders = NULL) %>%
  hot_col("factor_allow", allowInvalid = TRUE) %>%
  hot_col("Header",renderer = color_renderer)
```

[image]